# How to attach a database using a program deployed by C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

i wanna to attach a Database from a dynamic path to a MSSQL server by coding a project to do this  ,,
what is the code i should write and will it be a Windows Application or Console Application ,, or there is no difference ??

Comment: Not enough information. What kind of dynamic path? What database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [connecting to sql server through a .net winform application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151733/connecting-to-sql-server-through-a-net-winform-application)

Comment: any path the user insert ,, and 2 files database .mdf and .ldf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the connection string you can attach a database if the database has not already been attached. To do this in C# you should be able to do the following (this is untested):

```
    SQLConnection conn;
    try
    {
        conn = new SQLConnection(String.Format("Server={0};AttachDbFilename={1};Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;", "Server Address", @"Path To Database"));
        conn.Open();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

Let me know how you get on.

Regards,

Stu

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the two. Just make sure the files are in a place the SQL Server in question can reach and then attach them with an sql statement.

Like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE [AdventureWorks] ON
( FILENAME = N’C:\Data\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf’ ),
( FILENAME = N’C:\Data\AdventureWorks_Log.ldf’ )
FOR ATTACH
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about using System.Data.SqlConnection class?

You can dynamically build your connectionString when you create your SqlConnection.

Answer (score 0):

If I nderstand your question correctly, you are looking for a way to use a databse which the user will select (not the hard coded one).

Go here and learn about [Saving User and Application Settings in WinForms](http://codehill.com/2009/01/saving-user-and-application-settings-in-winforms/). You will get some ideas.